# External URL Redirect Breaking Image Links

Tags: 7, media, uri

I was recently hired to manage an existing Drupal 7 site (built with an Omega subtheme) and am doing my best to ramp up quickly. Unfortunately, I do have some fires to put out immediately and could really use some help. The website has redirects coming in from another hosting provider/domain manager. For example, www.oldsite.com is being redirected to www.currentdrupalsite.com (currentdrupalsite.com being the site that I am managing) from a different host than the one that the current Drupal site is being hosted on. This redirect is breaking my image links, specifically the logo.

So, the img src path is `http://oldsite.com/sites/all/themes/themename/logo.png` instead of `http://currentdrupalsite.com/sites/all/themes/themename/logo.png`.

Can I fix this through the Drupal interface?

Comment: what is the url of broken image? It the file there in location?

Answer (score 0):

A redirect from the old site to the new should not affect how the page is rendered on the new unless some absolute paths are hardcoded in the template files.

First check the value of `$base_url` in the settings.php.
If that is correct (or just commented out) check the code of your theme's template files.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the feedback. I checked settings.php and the base URL is commented out. Is there anything specific I am looking for in the theme's template files? Inside the templates folder are several sub-folders with templates. I can look through all of them if I know what I'm looking for. Would it be a base url as well?

Comment: It really depends on your theme's structure.
Check to see whether the logo URL is hardcoded in a tempate file. You might find it in page.tpl.php. Also check your theme's settings/options in Appearance > Settings > Your theme.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can find in the theme's files. I checked the theme's settings under Appearance in the Drupal interface. It's set to 'use the default logo.' The image link path in Firebug is now showing an IP address. So, it looks like: "<img alt="Southland Industries" src="http://127.0.0.1/sites/all/themes/southland2013/logo.png">" It tends to put in different paths, then correct itself, then break again. Thank you again for your help!